# How do I run this Python project I found on GitHub?

Tags: python, project

I am a newbie.
This is the project I want to run:
https://github.com/app-generator/django-dashboard-atlantis-dark

I installed requirements successfully. 
When I try to: python manage.py makemigrations, nothing happens.

I tried to google a solution and spent two tons of neurons.
If the crying is a solution I would do it.

Comment: U do not need this just follow this steps. In ur IDE terminal just run the two cmd. First One is >>> pip3 install -r requirements.txt    then the second one is >> python manage.py migrate  After that just run this >>python manage.py runserver  if no error occurs u will see a link just link this http://127.0.0.1:8000/   Have fun!!!!!

Comment: thank you for the help. I've done the things you described. After installing requirements I type python manage.py and nothing happens. Happens nothing more than just pressing enter. Like this:

C:\Users\kopsu\Desktop\django-dashboard-atlantis-dark-master>python manage.py makemigrations

C:\Users\kopsu\Desktop\django-dashboard-atlantis-dark-master>

What could be the issue?

Comment: if there is no pblm just connect me with teamviewer i will help to solve your problem,

Comment: No problem of course. ID: 1 614 015 174, pass: eua966

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need this, If you are familiar with how to use Virtual Env. on Pythons project in Windows then nothing to worry. Otherwise you need to create (Env) before running some command line. Just follow these steps below.

```
01. Check using cmd ...\> py --version if it was installed then follow the below 
    steps
02. cmd ...\> py -m pip install virtualenvwrapper-win 
03. cmd ...\> mkvirtualenv myproject
04. cmd ...\> workon myproject
05. cmd ...\> py -m pip install Django
06. Now Open the project by an IDE you are prefer to be use. Better use Pycharm 
    for python projects.
07. Run  cmd ...\> workon myproject ; then call your project directory and lastly 
    run
08. cmd ...\> py manage.py runserver; if you got an error about table 
     related just use this cmd ...\> py manage.py migrate
```

Comment: here are the useful links related this topic.                                                                                   
1. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/windows/                                                               
2. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/